# CSRF verification failed: Django 1.5.0

Tags: django, csrf, django-authentication, django-csrf, django-login

I'm running a really basic `django` login app (I thought) based on the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/) and...it's still not working no matter what I'm doing, and I've been looking through every single question on StackOverflow and not finding the answer. I'm running django.VERSION 1.5.0.

Every single thing I add or do to the code, I still get a `CSRF verification failed` error.

Inside my **portal/views.py**:

```
@cache_page(60 * 15)
@csrf_protect
def index(request, id=None):
    return render_to_response('undercovercoders/index.html',     context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@cache_page(60 * 15)
def login_user(request):
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get['username']
        password = request.POST.get['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)            
                state = "You're successfully logged in!"
            else:
                state = "Your account is not active, please contact the site admin."
        else:
            state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."
    return render_to_response('undercovercoders/index.html', {'state':state, 'username':username}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Inside my **portal/templates/index.html**:

```
 <div id="login-box">
            {% if form.errors %} 
            <p>Your username and password didn't match! Please try again!</p>
            {% endif %}
            {{ state }}
            <form class="login-widgets" action="/login/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                Username : 
                <input class="login-widgets-text" type="text" name="username" value="{{ username }}" />
                {{ form.username }}<br />
                Password :
                <input type="password" name="password" value="{{ password }}" />
                {{ form.password }}<br />
                <input class="login-button" type="submit" value="login" />
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
            </form>
```

In my **urls.py** /login/ is defined with the following

```
(r'^login/$', 'portal.views.login'),
```

My **settings.py** is the following:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

Please help, I've been wrestling with this error all evening.

EDIT: My console returns this to me when I added the changed to my render :

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py:59: UserWarning: A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.
  warnings.warn("A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.")

[07/Aug/2013 21:44:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2881
[07/Aug/2013 21:44:25] "GET /static/css/screen.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[07/Aug/2013 21:44:29] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2282
```

Comment: You wrote a custom login view, but then your url points to the built in django login view. So you might want to change that. Also look into including {% csrf_token %} in your html.

Comment: Thanks for looking through. The token is in the html. It doesn't matter if I change it to the custom, or use built-in, it doesn't work.

Comment: @csrf_exempt
is a workaround, don't use it often tho

Comment: @Ibrahim You mean add @csrf_exempt?

Comment: import the csrf_exempt decorator

from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
and place the @csrf_exempt decorator before the "def login_user(request):" statement.

Comment: I'm still getting the 'CSRF cookie not set' error, even with the decorator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your views

```
return render(request, 'template/index.html', {'state':state, 'username':username}, c)
```

you should do

```
return render(request, 'template/index.html', {'state':state, 'username':username})
```

Right now you are passing c in place of context_instance argument that forces the use of a RequestContext.

Comment: I'm still getting the error. Should I be using context_instance instead of c ?

Comment: I just saw that you added {...} I'll put that in and see

Comment: The moment I added `from django.template import RequestContext` to views.py the error went away, and your edit worked. Brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: @gersande it should have worked with render you shouldn't have to change it to render_to_response as render adds RequestContext you don't have to explicitly add it unless you are trying to provide 'context_instance' in your kwargs